# DSO breaks my php code

Tags: php, apache, handler

I just requested from my hosting company that APC be installed, after which they told me they'd have to switch the PHP handler from suPHP to DSO + modruid2 or FastCGI, I opted for DSO.

But now my website is broken! The page is full of warnings that the included files are not found. Like this:

```
Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/mydomain/public_html/index.php on line 14

Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mydomain/public_html/index.php on line 14
```

Is there some permissions problem? What configuration changes are needed for DSO to function? Could it be that modruid2 wasn't installed properly? Or is the problem caused because of APC? I really don't have much experience with PHP handlers, and I can't seem to find a solution with my hosting company or by searching the web!

### Edit

This is line 14, which is causing the above error - it was working perfectly normally before the DSO issue:

```
include ("include/header.php");
```

And I'm getting similar errors for everywhere I've included files.

Answer (score 0):

As a former Linux systems administrator for a web host, the most common solutions to these problems involved correcting permissions following a PHP handler switch.  The admin who made the switch should have done this as a part of making the switch, but permissions don't get automatically updated when a PHP handler gets switched, and different handlers sometimes have slightly different permissions requirements.  The fact that your website is throwing errors complaining about being unable to open files that you can verify haven't been touched, deleted, or moved, is fairly consistent with permissions issues.  I'd send in a follow-up request with your web host and have them make sure your file/directory permissions are correct for DSO.